# Is there a library like werkzeug's ProxyFix to fix the request.remote_addr but for Quart / Hypercorn ASGI servers?

Tags: werkzeug, quart, hypercorn

I am trying to run a Quart app behind an NGINX reverse proxy, but need to be able to use the `request.remote_addr` to determine the ip address of the client connection. When doing this with Flask I've always used the werkzeug `ProxyFix` package here:
https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/middleware/proxy_fix/

My nginx config looks like this:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
    }
```

And then in the python code I'm using this route to test:

```
@app.route('/whatsmyip')
async def whatsmyip():
    return request.remote_addr
```

When requests come through they always say the remote_addr is `127.0.0.1`, because that's the ip of the nginx instance.

Any pointers to how to implement this with nginx+hypercorn+quart would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solvable by using the `uvicorn.middleware.proxy_headers.ProxyHeadersMiddleware` middleware, for example:

```py
# app.py
from quart_trio import QuartTrio
from quart import request
from uvicorn.middleware.proxy_headers import ProxyHeadersMiddleware

app = QuartTrio(__name__)
app.asgi_app = ProxyHeadersMiddleware(app.asgi_app, trusted_hosts=["127.0.0.1"])

@app.route('/whatsmyip')
async def whatsmyip():
    return request.remote_addr
```

This will process the `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers, allowing it to correctly work with this NGINX configuration running on the same server:

```
server {
    server_name example.org;

    # Snakeoil SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    location / { 
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
    }   
}
```

You don't even need to use Uvicorn to run the python app, as the middleware isn't dependent on running under uvicorn, so you can use Hypercorn:
`hypercorn --worker-class trio --bind 127.0.0.1:5001 app.py`